# print array value no address

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I have this code:

```
int main ()
{
    unsigned long x[1000][1000];
    unsigned long y[10]={0};
    unsigned long num = 10;
    unsigned long i=0,j=0,a=0, b=0;
    printf("Hello\n");

        char ch;

        for (j=2;j<=num;j++)
        {
         a=0;
             for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
             {
                 if(j%i==0)
                 a++;
             }
             if (a==2)
             {
                 sleep(0.100);
                 printf("\n %lu ", j);
                 y[i]=j;
                 printf("array: %lu", y[i]);
             }
         }


        for(b=1;b<=10;b++){
            printf("\n array[%lu]: %lu", b,y[b]);
        }

        sleep(0.300);
        scanf("%c",&ch);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
Hello

 2 array: 2
 3 array: 3
 5 array: 5
 7 array: 7
 array[1]: 0
 array[2]: 0
```

But I dont know why at the second loop always print 0 for array value. 
Thanks in advance.
I saw some similar topics but I could not find the right solution.

Comment: What do you think you're writing to in `y[i]=j;`?

Comment: I highly encourage you to learn how to use a debugger

Comment: prime number, 2,3,5,7..

Comment: Indexing array out of bounds. You can index an array from `[0]` to `[length-1]`. For example `for(b=1;b<=10;b++)` should be `for(b=0;b<10;b++)`

Comment: Array indexing in C is zero-based, so if you declare an array `y[10]`, the valid indices are 0 through 9.  You seem to be ignoring the first element, `y[0]`, then indexing past the end of the array at `y[10]`.  Fix your code to confine your indexing to the range 0 through 9.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, array indexing was the problem. Sorry guys.
(b=0;b<9;b++) OK

Answer (score 0):

```
 y[i]=j;
```

The value of i = 11 always when the above statement is executed.

If you change `for(b=1;b<=10;b++)` to `for(b=1;b<=11;b++)` then you can see output:

```
array[11]: 7
```